# Add page-specific javascript or CSS in Joomla

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

How do you include a javascript or CSS file only on a certain article in Joomla?

I have one article which requires the jQuery UI and associated theme. Since this isn't being used on any other pages, I only want it for this particular article. Adding in the necessary `<script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet">` tags in the HTML of the article doesn't work, since they get stripped out when saved.

If there was a method to include certain files, or to stop the stripping of those tags, that'd be really good.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573831/joomla-load-script-in-a-specific-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up creating a plugin to do this for a site I maintain; I may release the code for it, but it's pretty simple to explain. You build a content plugin that searches for tags like `{css path/to/a/css/file.css}`, strips them out, then adds the files to the HTML `<head>`. Once you have the name of the CSS or JS file you want to include, here is the code you use to get it in the header:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base() . 'path/to/style.css');
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'path/to/script.js');
```

Answer (score 4):

For this job use the Joomla plugin "Sourcerer". You can put PHP and Javascript in articles with it and still have time left to bake a pie!
I just added the code to the article and it worked like a charm. Beware of evil editors that will strip parts of the code. Html Entities are your friend - you can use them.
Sample code:

```
{source}<?php
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet( JURI::root( true ).'/example.css' );
$doc->addCustomTag( '<script src="/example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' );
$doc->addScript( JURI::root( true ).'/example.js' );
?>{/source}
```

Comment: Awesome! This was exactly what I needed to easily add a Google Lead Conversion code in a Joomla page.

Answer (score 0):

Set your editor to `Editor - None`, and use any `<script>` and `<style>` that you want.

Don't forget that you should avoid editing that article using TinyMCE or other editors later.