# Joomla load script in a specific page

Tags: php, joomla

I'm creating a website in Joomla and wondering if there is a way to load a specific script in a specific page using php....

e.g. i want to load a :
`<script src="sample.js">` in the about us page where it is going to be use

the reason why I wanted to do this is that instead of having them all load in head section even if it is not being use in the page makes page slower...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758667/add-page-specific-javascript-or-css-in-joomla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do this in a content item or a component? If you're trying to do it in a component, this is the way to add a JavaScript file to the head portion for *only* that page:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'path/to/sample.js');
```

If you're trying to do this in a content item, you'll most likely need to find or build a content plugin to scan for a token that tells Joomla to run code like above. I did this on one of the sites I built a while back. I had it set so that a plugin would search for tags like {js sample.js} in content items, extract the file name, add the script to the document, then search and replace the tag out of the article.

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org has several plugins/modules to allow inclusion of scripts and advanced HTML/PHP.

Comment: trying to add it in a content item with a animated collapsible div e.g. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm (Example 4)