# Page-specific logic in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am trying to enable JavaScript in a Joomla template to behave differently depending on the page. In particular, I have set the [Key Reference](http://docs.joomla.org/Screen.content.edit.15#Parameters_-_Advanced) as that appears to be the most appropriate value I could find for this purpose. Unfortunately, I can't seem to access it in my code. I tried:

```
$this->params->get("keyref")
```

and a few other variations, but they simply returned a blank. How can I retrieve this value or is there a better way of writing page specific logic.

**Related Articles**

- [Joomla load script in a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573831/joomla-load-script-in-a-specific-page): This would work, but seems like overkill for what I want to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each page can be given an [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596621/explanation-of-alias-attribute-in-joomla). We can retrieve the alias using [code from the forum](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=330969):

```
function getCurrentAlias()
{
   $menu   = &JSite::getMenu();
   $active   = $menu->getActive();
   return $active->alias;
}
```

We can then inject this into the Javascript:

```
var alias= '<?php echo getCurrentAlias(); ?>';
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of keyref, but I would solve it by using the class suffix parameter you can set for each menu entry.[see](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Using_Class_Suffixes_in_Joomla!_1.5#When_Would_You_Use_a_Class_Suffix.3F) I would use a space in front of this suffix. With javascript you can then try to read this classname (suffix without the space) on each page.

```
getElementsByClassName("mysuffix");
```

for example

If this returns multiple objects, you know on which page you are. Will that help you?

Comment: See the [documentation on keyref](http://docs.joomla.org/Screen.content.edit.15#Parameters_-_Advanced)

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that this is the best solution for this problem, but being aware of that is useful